# Protractor Iterate through ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a following code

```
<div class="btn btn-success form-control ng-binding" ng-click="test(uid)">
                First
            </div>
    <div class="btn btn-success form-control ng-binding" ng-click="test(uid)">
                Second
            </div>
<div class="btn btn-success form-control ng-binding" ng-click="test(uid)">
                Third
            </div>
```

How do i iterate elements based on ng-click to check for a specific text value(First or Second or Third) in Protractor?I  tried the following but i get undefined for uids.length. What is wrong here?

```
var uids = element.all(by.css('[ng-click="test(uid)"]'));
for(var i=0;i<uids.length;i++)
console.log(uids.get(i).getText());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is [element.all()](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) returns an `ElementArrayFinder` rather than a simple array. If you look at the linked documentation you'll see some functions that allow you to easily interact that data structure. I believe you want to use the [each()](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) function like so:

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-click="test(uid)"]')).each(function(element, index) {
  element.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
  });
});
```

Also worth noting that the [getText()](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) function, like nearly all functions in Protractor, returns a promise and therefore needs to be resolved before you can access the value you really want.